# Task Manager and all other admin right required system apps not opening on click

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have been using windows 10 without any problem until i installed a third party app from a specific site and installed.

After that, Task manager does't opens up when i press ctrl+alt+del

Many options in controll panel wont open until i got to their system folder and opening it from its folder location and right click and choose run as administrator.

I think the software containing some malware almost changed everything related to permissions in windows registry.

If so,Where can i modify that stuff to default,
I mean there a lot of stuffs like HKEY_CLASS and all like that.
I dont know where excactly there configurations are...
Let me know so that i can play around and tweak them back to normal if i am in right place...
Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, you can still get the UAC prompt if you explicitly say "run as Administrator" on the program?

Comment: yea...but its really difficult to track down each one's location and set it's property as always run as admin.I just want to make what was changed by malware back to normal or default